# How to send localStorage keys from Chrome Extension to localhost?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

Hello im creating a chrome extension, and I save data (username, avtarUrl etc) in localStorage but i want to share/send this data in the localStorage of my localhost too.

How can i do that ?

Comment: To read/write localStorage of a web page on localhost you need a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) that matches localhost, see [how to access the webpage DOM?](/a/4532567).

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging